# Unable to load pdf from local disk with advance_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render a PDF with the library "advance_pdf_viewer". The process is as follows

1. The PDF gets downloaded from external API
2. The PDF is stored on the local device using path_provider and dart:io File
3. The PDF is loaded with advance_pdf_viewer PDFDocument.fromFile(file)

As far as I can tell step 1 and two are working as expected since I am able to locate the downloaded PDF in the applications folder within the device - and the PDF can be opened with the PDF readers I have tested.

The code that will download, store and display the PDF:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    DocumentDownloader downloader = DocumentDownloader(widget.document);

    downloader.download(context).then((data) {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        /// Send the PDF to the HTML document
      } else {
        downloader.storeFileData(context, data).then((local) {
          if (local == null) {
            return;
          }

          PDFDocument.fromFile(local).then((document) async {
            setState(() {
              pdf = document;
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The class that handle network requests:

```
class DataProvider {
  static const String DOWNLOAD_FILE_ENDPOINT = "/api/document/downloadfile";

  Future<Uint8List> downloadFileData({
    String filename,
  }) {
    print(filename);
    return http
        .post(
      "${DataService.normalizeEndpoint(DOWNLOAD_FILE_ENDPOINT)}?filename=$filename",
      headers: DataService.validateHeader(null),
    )
        .then((res) {
      return res.bodyBytes;
    });
  }
}

class DocumentDownloader {
   final Document document;

   DocumentDownloader(this.document);

   Future<Uint8List> download(BuildContext context) {
      return DataProvider().downloadFileData(filename: document.filename);
   }

   Future<dynamic> storeFileData(
     BuildContext context,
     Uint8List data,
   ) {
     if (data == null) {
       return Future.value(null);
     }


     return getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
       io.File local = io.File("${directory.path}/${document.filename}");

       return local.writeAsBytes(
         data,
         flush: true,
       );
     });
   }
 }
```

This is the error message I get when the viewer is trying to load the PDFDocument, my assumption is that the PDFDocument.fromFile does not manage to load the PDF due to a to me, unknown reason (since the PDF exists)

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:37:52)
#1      _PDFViewerState._loadPage (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/viewer.dart:110:15)
#2      _PDFViewerState.didChangeDependencies (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/viewer.dart:89:5)
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4723:12)
#4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4538:5)
#5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3508:14)
#6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3263:20)
#7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4589:16)
#8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4280:5)
#9      ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4924:5)
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3253
```

I have tested to use PDFDocument.fromURL and that works as expected so there has to be something wrong with my setup...

Hope to get some tips here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not count as an answer but I want to get it out there as an alternative for those whom might be struggling with the same.

After quite some time struggling with the `advance_pdf_viewer` I changed the PDF-reader library to `flutter_pdfview` and that did the trick.

I had to create my own navigation buttons (go to first page, go previous, go next and go to last page) along with a current page / total page widget but that was just a few minutes of coding anyhow.

I can't say whether the `advance_pdf_viewer` is better or worse than `flutter_pdfview` but the `flutter_pdfview` works more than good enough for my client and in my case, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a conflict of dart.io in document.dart (part of advance_pdf_viewer).

change...
import 'dart:io';
to
import 'dart:io' as io;

then in
static Future fromFile(File file) async

to
static Future fromFile(io.File file) async